# How to reposition CITYGML files?

Tags: gis, ogc

Assume you have an example file for CIGYML, e.g. the [FZK-Haus](https://www.citygmlwiki.org/upload/EnergyADE%202.0/SampleData%20KIT/FZKHouseLoD3/FZK-Haus-LoD3-MultiZone-ADE.gm). How can the geo coordinates in the building be changed in a reproducible way?

I've tried the workflow proposed by [HfT-Stuttgart](https://simstadt.hft-stuttgart.de/advanced-topics/add-buildings-to-city-gml-files/). However, it is required to use an old version of SketchUp, so the workflow is not reproducible with different systems. Additionally, the information in the ADE are lost.

What options do I have to reposition the building without using the ADE information?